# SQL Server Docker

Tags: sql-server, docker

estoy intentando usar `SQL Server` desde docker pero no funciona, si uso `docker-compose.yml` nunca se levanta.

Y si uso `docker run` logra funcionar pero no puedo conectarme, sale error de autenticacion para `sa`

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  mssql:
    container_name: db_mssql
    user: '0:0'
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: 'Y'
      SA_PASSWORD: '123456'
      MSSQL_PID: 'Express'
    volumes:
      - volume:/var/opt/mssql
    ports: 
      - 1433:1433
volumes:
  volume:
```

en cuanto a `docker run` no acepta volumen, logra levantar pero no puedo conectarme

```
docker run --name sqlserver -p 1433:1433 -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASWORD=123456" -e "MSSQL_PID=Express" -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu problema es de autenticación. [Aquí puedes encontrar más detalles acerca del error 18456](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error?view=sql-server-ver15). Estás seguro que el formato del server name es correcto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola @user75463 el error que tienes se puede solventar, leyendo los logs de salida del contenedor ya sea con un programa como `Kitematic` o `Docker Dashboard` o a trabes del comando `docker logs CONTAINER`, revisando podrás encontrar el siguiente mensaje:

> ERROR: Unable to set system administrator password: Password
> validation failed. The password does not meet SQL Server password
> policy requirements because it is too short. The password must be at
> least 8 characters..

Esto quiere decir que el contenedor falla porque la contraseña no cumple con los requisitos mínimos, por lo cual `12345678` tampoco valdría porque tendrías el siguiente error:

> ERROR: Unable to set system administrator password: Password
> validation failed. The password does not meet SQL Server password
> policy requirements because it is not complex enough. The password
> must be at least 8 characters long and contain characters from three
> of the following four sets: Uppercase letters, Lowercase letters, Base
> 10 digits, and Symbols..

Con lo cual si realizamos el cambio de la contraseña a una que cumpla los requisitos el contenedor debería funcionaria, el comando corregido quedaría:

> docker run --name sqlserver -p 1433:1433 -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e
> "SA_PASSWORD=Stack2021" -e "MSSQL_PID=Express" -d
> mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest

Otro punto que también podrías tener en cuenta es que yo tuve problemas en algunas versiones de contenedores `MSSQL` con la contraseña y lo solucione cambiando `SA_PASSWORD` a `MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD` pero segun el ejemplo que colocas funciona con el comando corregido que te dejado.